# Preventing an object from landing on its side; ensuring it always lands face-up or face-down

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Currently I am doing a project of shell toss in Unity. The shell is made in Blender and imported in Unity. I attached a single box collider to the shell.

Now when I apply the random force to the shell to flip it, it sometimes rests in the vertical up position when either a result of heads (face-up) or tails (face-down) should have occurred.

I have tried changing the axis, increasing the gravity. But none of these solutions worked.

What I have done for now is when the shell is in a resting position after it lands, I rotate the shell 90 degrees - but this is not a great solution, since it is slow and takes time to check whether the shell has come to rest or not.

I am looking for the better idea so that the shell should only rests in a heads or tails state.

Comment: Are you using the physics in Unity? I would imagine narrowing the collider would help. Additionally, when you export a model in Blender you can specify the how the Axises are mapped.

Comment: Yeah i am using Physics. I have made minimum possible collider. Didn't helped.

Comment: Can you show a GIF of the unexpected behaviour you're getting? That could help clear up some uncertainty around what your problem is.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9QulIa45Z6hLTZURkw0OUN2YXc

In this image the Blue circled is fine but red one is not fine.

@Serlite

Comment: Interesting...uh, those look a bit more like shells than coins. Anyways, what kind of collider do you have on them? Is that just how they happen to end up landing, and you want to prevent that outcome?

Comment: @Serlite I want to prevent the vertical upside down and only want front side or backside to occur. I have: Box Collider and rigid body property. i apply random force and when they land, they should land only in front side or backside. Since the shell is flat in front and backside.

Comment: Sounds like what you could do is add 2-3 capsule colliders in a cross shape to the object instead, where the tips of the capsule colliders correspond to the front/back/sides of the shell. This way, if the shell lands on an edge like that, it will roll on the tips of the capsule colliders until it is either face up or down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134207/discussion-between-sudeep-acharya-and-serlite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a box collider for your shells, you are going to end up in this problematic situation where the flipped shell sometimes ends up sitting sideways, instead of face-up or face-down.

In this situation, I would recommend making use of [Capsule Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CapsuleCollider.html?_ga=1.167375736.737126767.1485292136), which are cylindrical colliders with a rounded top and bottom. If a capsule collider lands on either end, it'll fall over sideways:

[image]

However, one capsule collider isn't enough - otherwise, the shell will start rolling around after it falls over. I suggest 2 or 3, oriented in a cross such that their tips correspond to the sides of the shell:

[image]

Now, if the shell lands on any of its sides, it will topple over onto one of the faces of the cross - either face-up, or face-down. To add capsule colliders to your GameObjects, just click on Add Component, and select Physics > Capsule Collider. Then modify the properties to get them into the desired positions:

[image]

The Direction you choose should probably be X-Axis and Z-Axis. Once you have the correct orientation, change the Center value to move the colliders to the right positions to make a cross through the shell. Then, alter the Radius of the colliders to affect the thickness of the cross, and the Height so their tips line up with the edges of the shell.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It works, thank you so much, but the colliding point is terrible i.e the object are penetrating the walls, i think i cannot add box collider side by side. What can be the good solution?

Comment: Great! Really glad I could help out.

Comment: @SudeepAcharya Hmm, penetrating through walls? Are your colliders lined up with the edges of the object to match its shape as closely as possible? What does their arrangement look like now?